# Shell - source program C is given, Determine for each function in the source, the number of calls, and the lines where the call occurs

Tags: shell

I have this, but when I run the shell.sh script, it says line 15: syntax error: unexpected end of file. Any idea anyone?

Shell.sh:

```
if [ $# -eq 0 ] ; then  
 echo "parameters don't exist"  
else  
 for i in $@  
 do   
  awk -f scen.awk test.c | while read functie # test.c - name of the source program  
  do  
  #echo $function  
  grep -n "$function" test.c   # test.c - name of the source program  
  nr=`grep -c $function`  
  echo $nr  
  done         
 done  
fi
```

Scen.awk:

```
BEGIN { level=0; }  
{  
if (index($0,"{")<1)   
  {if ((level==0) && (index($0,"(")>0) && (index($0,")")>0))  
    {split($0, a, "(");  # we cut until '('  
     split(a[1], b, " ");  
     n = 1;  
     for (i in b) n++;  
     print b[n-1];   # the name of the function is the last component of the array b  
    }  
   if (index($0,"{")>0)   
     level++;  
   if (index($0,"}")>0)  
     level--;  
  }  
}
```

Comment: It usually says that when there is a missing closing done or fi or parenthesis. But I don't see one.

Comment: FWIW it all runs OK for me (at least in the sense of not producing syntax errors; I haven't tried feeding it real C code or checking whether the actual output makes sense) in Cygwin. I haven't tried on a real Unix system.

Answer (score 0):

to fix it take a look at the line 6:

if [ $# -eq 0 ] ; then
 echo "parameters don't exist"
else
 for i in $@
 do
  awk -f scen.awk test.c | while read **function** # test.c - name of the source program
  do
  #echo $function
  grep -n "$function" test.c   # test.c - name of the source program
  nr=`grep -c $function`
  echo $nr
  done
 done
fi

but it seems you have other problem in the awk file. I will try to to take a look.
hope it helps.